# How can I dismiss some classes when creating dataset in pytorch?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, torch

It is my first experience with PyTorch. I cloned the repository to google colab. There are some classes (image folders) in the repository that I want to dismiss (let's say folder cat). How can I achieve that? I do not want to simply remove that class from the directory.

```py
dataaddress = 'blah/blah' # address where all the classes resides
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(dataaddress, transform=train_transform)
test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(dataaddress, transform=eval_transform)

train_indexes = [idx for idx in range(len(train_dataset)) if idx % 5] 
test_indexes = [idx for idx in range(len(test_dataset)) if not idx % 5]


train_dataset = Subset(train_dataset, train_indexes)
test_dataset = Subset(test_dataset, test_indexes)
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @krivar I posted it

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code

```
filep= os.path.join(root, splitp)

with open(filep, 'r') as splitfile:
  for line in splitfile:
    textlabel=line.split('/')[0].rstrip()
    if textlabel != 'BACKGROUND_Google':
      self.labels.append(textlabel)
      self.labels_idx.append(class_to_idx[textlabel])
      self.images.append(pil_loader(os.path.join(root, line.rstrip())))
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this code does and how it solves the problem?

Comment: So in the root directory there are 2 text files "train.txt" and "test.txt" which was provided to split the data, structured in this way:

accordion/image_0001.jpg
airplanes/image_0150.jpg


. "filep" above is path to those files and "splitp" is an argument that takes values "train" or "test". Rest is reading those files and discarding "BACKGROUND_Google"

Comment: It would be more helpful if you included the explanation in the answer itself where your code can be properly formatted etc.